# Travis CI env variables ";" expected

Tags: android, continuous-integration, environment-variables, travis-ci

This is my first attempt at CI/CD using TravisCI.

I'm trying to set it up so that my API key is encrypted. I'm having strange Ruby issues on my machine so encrypting the key via terminal is not an option and I need to define the variable in the repository settings.

- I've stored my API key in my `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` as 
  `LUCKY_COINS_API_KEY= "abcd-1234"`
- Then i've added an environment variable to my repo via TravisCI with same name and value as above, ive tried adding it with ';' and without.
- In my app `build.gradle` I have the following lines.

  ```
  buildTypes {
  release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      buildConfigField 'String', 'LUCKY_COINS_API_KEY', apiKey()
  }
  debug {
      minifyEnabled true
      buildConfigField 'String', 'LUCKY_COINS_API_KEY', apiKey()
  }
  ```

  }

  ```
  def apiKey() {
  if (project.hasProperty("LUCKY_COINS_API_KEY")) {
      return project.properties["LUCKY_COINS_API_KEY"]
  } else if (System.getenv("LUCKY_COINS_API_KEY") != null) {
      return System.getenv("LUCKY_COINS_API_KEY")
  } else {
      throw Exceptions("Set API Key")
  }
  }
  ```

So now when project is build on CI, it can access the API key since TravisCI has no way of pulling values out of my local home gradle.properties. The problem is I get the following errors:

All of them are located in the remote `BuildConfig.java`

```
e: /home/travis/build/accountName/Lucky-Coins/app/build/generated/source/buildConfig/debug/com/example/luckycoins/BuildConfig.java:14: error: ';' expected
  public static final String LUCKY_COINS_API_KEY = [secure];
                                                    ^
e: /home/travis/build/accountName/Lucky-Coins/app/build/generated/source/buildConfig/debug/com/example/luckycoins/BuildConfig.java:14: error: <identifier> expected
  public static final String LUCKY_COINS_API_KEY = [secure];
                                                           ^
e: /home/travis/build/accountName/Lucky-Coins/app/build/generated/source/buildConfig/debug/com/example/luckycoins/BuildConfig.java:14: error: <identifier> expected
  public static final String LUCKY_COINS_API_KEY = [secure];
                                                                ^
e: /home/travis/build/accountName/Lucky-Coins/app/build/generated/source/buildConfig/debug/com/example/luckycoins/BuildConfig.java:14: error: illegal start of type
  public static final String LUCKY_COINS_API_KEY = [secure];
                                                                 ^
e: /home/travis/build/accountName/Lucky-Coins/app/build/generated/source/buildConfig/debug/com/example/luckycoins/BuildConfig.java:14: error: <identifier> expected
  public static final String LUCKY_COINS_API_KEY = [secure];
                                                                   ^
e: /home/travis/build/accountName/Lucky-Coins/app/build/generated/source/buildConfig/debug/com/example/luckycoins/BuildConfig.java:14: error: ';' expected
  public static final String LUCKY_COINS_API_KEY = [secure];
                                                                     ^
e: /home/travis/build/accountName/Lucky-Coins/app/build/generated/source/buildConfig/debug/com/example/luckycoins/BuildConfig.java:14: error: illegal start of type
  public static final String LUCKY_COINS_API_KEY = [secure];
                                                                      ^
e: /home/travis/build/accountName/Lucky-Coins/app/build/generated/source/buildConfig/debug/com/example/luckycoins/BuildConfig.java:14: error: <identifier> expected
  public static final String LUCKY_COINS_API_KEY = [secure];
                                                                          ^
e: /home/travis/build/accountName/Lucky-Coins/app/build/generated/source/buildConfig/debug/com/example/luckycoins/BuildConfig.java:14: error: ';' expected
  public static final String LUCKY_COINS_API_KEY = [secure];
                                                                           ^
e: /home/travis/build/accountName/Lucky-Coins/app/build/generated/source/buildConfig/debug/com/example/luckycoins/BuildConfig.java:14: error: <identifier> expected
  public static final String LUCKY_COINS_API_KEY = [secure];
```

I cant access this file so I'm having trouble debugging this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape quotes if you want to add a string as a repository variable..

So make sure to put "\"API_KEY_HERE\""